# How to get datetime format of SQL column in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, datetime-format

I want to get format of a `datetime` column to be able to use it in C#. I want to get it and change my variable to this format. I could not find any solution. How to get it? I just want to be able to get the format of existing column and use it as string in C#.

Answer (score 4):

DateTime values in SQL Server are stored as binary values that are not human readable. They are not strings at all.

For C#, you should use the normal .Net primitive `DateTime` type to talk to the database; **NEVER** use any string formats; reserve the string for when you output to the user. The ADO.Net library (which also sits underneath other tools like Entity Framework) will efficiently and safely handle transport between your application and SQL Server.

---

> I am building an sql query to search a string value as parameter that comes from frontend.

Great, we can do that. The way we do it to to **parse the string to a C# `DateTime`**, and then use the C# `DateTime` value for the query.

Let me elaborate. I'm worried you're wanting to do something like this:

```
string SQL = "SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [DateColumn] >= '" + TextBox1.Text "'";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, connection);
```

**THAT IS NOT OKAY!**

It is **NEVER** okay to use string concatenation to include user data like that. Instead, you must use **parameterized queries**. And when you do this, one of the things you can do is provide datetime values.

So instead, the code should look more like this:

```
string SQL = "SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [DateColumn] >= @MinDate";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MinDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
```

But even this is still a little rough, because users will do all kinds of things when entering a date into a raw textbox. You'll be much better off if you can also provide a datepicker that ensures you get a clean input from the user.

---

All that said, the SQL language does have specific formats for Datetime literal values. You can pick any of these formats and the database will handle it correctly:

> yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss[.fff]
> yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss[.fff]
> yyyyMMdd

Note the above formats are very specific and must be followed exactly, but if you do any of these can be cleanly converted to SQL Server datetime values. But again: this is *not* how the values are stored internally, the need for this should be relatively rare, and it's definitely **NOT** something you would **EVER** do for user input.

Comment: (`DateTime` isn't really a "primitive" type - it's a very normal `struct` type, just with its own `TypeCode`).

Comment: I just want to get the format of column as string like "YY/MM/DD" and change format of my datetime object using this string.I mean i just want to access the format of the column on c#.

Comment: @Fatih `DateTime.ToString("YY/MM/DD")` can do this, as well as many other things (string.Format(), interpolation, etc). But this is only well after you've read the value from the database. The database is going to give you a built-in `DateTime` value. It will **NOT** give you a string, so you have to make one. And you should definitely **NOT** try to format a string to write it back to database. Instead, parse to a `DateTime` value.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes, the actual problem is I don't know the format.And I want to get it from the database column.So I be able to change format of my DateTime object like your suggestion

Comment: @Fatih The database will give you a C# `DateTime` value. It will not give you a string. You must accept that DateTime value and convert it to a string later.

Comment: @Fatih Something to keep in mind: thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, converting between datetime values and strings is far slower and more error-prone than we'd like to believe. It's something to avoid. One might be tempted to think, okay, I'll just keep things as strings, but this only makes the problem worse. The actual solution is to keep things as `DateTime` objects as much as possible, and only convert to or from string at the point closest to the end user.

Comment: So, there are not any solution to get the format? Because I am building an sql query to search a string value as parameter that comes from frontend.And I want to change the format of this parameter.Because column format and parameter format must be the same.If it is not,i can not get correct result.

Comment: @Fatih: maybe your database is poorly designed and you really store a datetime as a string. Then you should focus on fixing this mess instead of finding workarounds. If the column you're talking about is of type `datetime`, there is no format at all and everything is fine. Then you should create  a new question to find a solution for the real issue, because this one is an xy-problem.

Comment: @Faith in that case, you should parse the value from the user into a c# DateTime, and then include the DateTime value as a parameter with the query. Again: if you have a `DateTime` column in  SQL Server, it is stored as a binary value. It is **NOT** stored as a string at all.

Comment: @Fatih I updated the answer with more detail.